# Is the cokernel of morphism of sheaves locally free?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Suppose that $C$ is a smooth curve over $\mathbb{C}$ and $E$ is a globally generated vector bundle of rank $r>1$ on $C$. A general section of $E$ gives an injective morphism
$$0\rightarrow O_C \rightarrow E\,.$$
The cokernel has rank $r-1$. Is it locally free?

How do we see this? It is enough to prove that $E$ is torsion free. But how do we see this?

Comment: The answer below shows what can go wrong, but if the rank $r>1$ (or more generally, rank is greater than the dimension) then what you ask is true and attributed to Serre.

Comment: Thank you very much. I was in fact asking about the $r>1$ case only. Can you please elaborate or give some reference.

Comment: It is standard and can be found in various forms. For example, you can find it in Mumford's book on curves on a surface. More general versions can be found in Eisenbud (albeit for affine case, though it can be easily modified for your case).

Comment: @Mohan. This cannot be true as you state it because one could consider the sequence in the counterexample below and add a globally generated vector bundle in the middle as a direct summand. Perhaps you want to assume that $E$ is indecomposable and of rank $r>1$.

Comment: @DamianRössler Serre does not say all sections will have the property, only general sections.

Comment: @Mohan. I see -  thank you for explaining.

Answer (score 3):

Take $C=\mathbb{P}^1$, $E=\mathcal{O}(1).$ Then you have the sequence

$$0\to\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}\to \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}(1)\to i_*\mathcal{O}_{\mathrm{pt}}\to0 $$ for $i$ an inclusion of a closed point. The cokernel is not locally free and is supported on a single point.